# Limit of the summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have recently been trying out the following limit
$$\lim _{a \rightarrow \infty}\left(2 \sqrt{a}-\frac{2 a^{3 / 2}}{3}+\frac{a^{5 / 2}}{5}+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{2(-1)^n a^{1 / 2(2 n+1)}}{(2 n+1) n !}\right)$$.

While it seems that we cannot evaluate it through some standard methods, [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Limit%5B2%5C%2840%29Power%5Ba%2CDivide%5B1%2C2%5D%5D%5C%2841%29-2Divide%5B%5C%2840%29Power%5Ba%2CDivide%5B3%2C2%5D%5D%5C%2841%29%2C3%5D%2BDivide%5BPower%5Ba%2CDivide%5B5%2C2%5D%5D%2C5%5D%2BSum%5BDivide%5B2Power%5B%5C%2840%29-1%5C%2841%29%2Cn%5DPower%5Ba%2CDivide%5B2n%2B1%2C2%5D%5D%2C%5C%2840%292n%2B1%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29n%21%5C%2841%29%5D%2C%7Bn%2C3%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D%2Ca-%3E%E2%88%9E%5D) gives $\sqrt{\pi}$ to be the answer. I tried evaluating it as the limit of a partial sum, but still not getting it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: First instinct tells me something about trigonometric functions

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Taylor_series) can help.

Comment: Thank you! It certainly eases it up!

Answer (score 6):

We can consider the following series and rewrite as follows

$$I(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)n!}=\int_0^x dt\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-t^2)^n}{n!}=\int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt$$

The limit in question is

$$\lim_{a\to\infty}2I(\sqrt{a})=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2}dt=\sqrt{\pi}$$

Comment: But how would you rewrite it as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)n!}$?

Comment: Just show that the first 3 terms match the pattern of the summand and substitute $x\to \sqrt{a}$

Comment: The first term is plainly $x$ in your summation, which would then $\to {a}$

Comment: If you expand out $2I(\sqrt{a})$ you'll see it's exactly the same as the series you're supposed to take the limit of.